# Returning an array of tuples

Tags: xcode, function, swift, lint

```
    func timesForDepartureStation(departureStation: Station, #arrivalStation: Station) -> Array<(departureTime: NSDate, arrivalTime: NSDate)>{
```

For some reason, the Xcode LINT tool completely stop me from compiling this line of code. It notes that the # is Extraneous (even though it's not and I just want the arrivalStation to be an external parameter as well), and when calling from an external class... it doesn't even recognize the second parameter. I have no clue why, but I've restarted Xcode numerous times and am very tempted to do a reinstall. Has anyone found a similar issue?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_213) this should not be a compiler error, but it is unnecessary as the behaviour you are looking for is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting my computer and Xcode fixed everything. Silly betas

Answer (score 0):

By default every parameter except the first uses the parameter name as the external name there is no need to force the second argument. So this func signature should give you what you want:

```
func timesForDepartureStation(departureStation: Station, arrivalStation: Station) -> Array<(departureTime: NSDate, arrivalTime: NSDate)>
```

Then you can call this function like this:

```
timesForDepartureStation(departStation, arrivalStation: arrStation)
```

If you want to force the first argument to use an external name you can use the `#` infront of  departureStation, but that is not necessary based on the name of the function.

As well if you are looking to not use named parameters for a function you must put an `_` in front of the parameter in the definition like so:

```
func timesForDepartureStation(departureStation: Station, _ arrivalStation: Station) -> Array<(departureTime: NSDate, arrivalTime: NSDate)>
```

Then it can be called like so:

```
timesForDepartureStation(departStation, arrStation)
```

Comment: That applies to methods (=functions within a class), but not standalone functions.